# Comparing time in sqlite database ios

Tags: ios, sql, database, sqlite, time

I am using a sqlite database which has a field for time which is not of any type. I want all the cars leaving after a particular time. I have written this query to fetch all cars after 23:00

SELECT A.carKey, A.stkey, A.time, B.stkey, B.time FROM timetable A , timetable B where A.carKey = B.carKey AND A.stkey = 'dsd' AND B.stkey = 'ddd' AND B.time > A.time AND (B.time - A.time) <12 AND  A.time>time('23:00')

**Where the table has a common carKey and A is the start point and B is the end point.**

but its not showing me cars after 12.00 am night. I want results in such a way that after 23:00 it should start considering trains after 12.00 am.

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `time` column?

Comment: I haven't entered any type.

Comment: I did not ask about the *type* of the *column* but about the *format* of the *values*. What exactly are you storing as time?

Comment: Im storing time in HH:mm format.

Comment: Please note that the `time` function returns a value in `hh:mm:ss` format; but this shouldn't hurt in this case.

Comment: Please edit your question to show some sample records and the expected results.